# Jvm mixed mode and JavaFx error

Tags: javafx, gluon, mixed-mode

I try to launch my javafx(gluon crosplatform) application on orange pi Armbian operation system.

```
Use zero,zulu,oracle jdk(try all).
Use embeded javafx from gluon.
Use -Dmonocle.platform = X11 Dprism.order = es2
```

I have very strange problem. The application does not work in jvm mixed mode but works ok (but very slow) in interpreted mode (`-Xint` command line argument). In mixed mode, the application can't get Egl display and throws an Exception:

```
com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.GLException: 0x3000: Could not get EGL display
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AcceleratedScreen.<init>(AcceleratedScreen.java:84)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatform.getAcceleratedScreen(NativePlatform.java:127)
        at com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(MonocleGLFactory.java:107)
        at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(ES2Pipeline.java:82)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(GraphicsPipeline.java:187)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:91)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I've run JavaFX on 'embedded' systems, and though it is possible it is sometimes quite a journey to find out. For a start does `/dev/fb0` exist?

Comment: Yes /dev/-fb0 exist. I can run application but fps is too low. If i use -Dmonocle.platform = Linux Dprism.order = sw , application work in mixed mode too. But there is no acceleration and application work slow too. But not so slow as in interpreted mode. Iwant to have 20 - 25 fps. If you know any method to run javafx on orange pi (any operation system) tell me pleeeease ))

Comment: Oracle has a [tutorial for Raspberry Pi](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RaspberryPiFX/raspberryfx.html).  Maybe it contains the solution for you.